# Selected Item in ListView with custom ArrayAdapter losing color on screen rotation in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am using a custom ListFragment with my custom ArrayAdapter.

In `getView()`, I set `parentListView.itemChecked(position, true)` based on a condition.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
if (null == mParentListView) {//mParentListView is an instance variable
            mParentListView = (ListView) parent;
        }
if (some condition) {
            mParentListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

I am also doing `setRetainInstance(true)` for the fragment. Therefore, I create a new instance of the arrayadapter in the fragment only if it is null.

```
if (null == mOptionsArrayAdapter) 
mOptionsArrayAdapter = new ModeOptionsArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                ModeTypeEnum.values(), mSelectedModeEnumId);

}
```

Everything works fine. However, when I rotate the screen, the selected item's color is lost. I mean the color specified in `listRow's textview colorStateList` is not applied.

Only when I allow the adapter to be created again on rotation (by removing the null check), it works.

I thought of reusing parent view in `OnCreateView()`. But doing this was discouraged in some StackOverflow answer.

**My row layout.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textViewModeOptionItem"
    style="@style/TripAppTextViewStyle.Big"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/trip_mode_options_text_indicator"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />
```

Is creating adapter every time the only solution?

**My Color State List xml - trip_mode_options_text_indicator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
<item android:color="@color/gray"/>

</selector>
```

When I first come to the activity, the selected/activated list row shows white text color and the rest show gray(as specified in my color state list), but when I rotate the screen, all rows show gray, including the one for which `mParentListView.setItemChecked` was set true.

Comment: Are you reusing the Fragment in the Activity after the orientation change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea behind this question was to get solution to prevent the creation of my custom list adapter on screen rotation. As my listAdapter reference is an instance variable, it is retained on screen rotation(due to fragment.setRetainInstance(true)). Still, the list item selection goes away. Therefore, as that is not working, the only way out is to create the list adapter every time in onActivityCreated() along with fragment.setRetainInstance(true).

Answer (score 1):

For the current class, you need to provide `configChanges` option in `AndroidManifest.xml` as below:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: @Steve Benett: Yes, I am reusing the fragment in my activity by doing setRetainInstance(true)

Comment: Is using android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" the only way? Coz, I want to avoid it as its use is discouraged.

Comment: As the Android Dev documentation says, You can use `configChanges` used only as a last resort. BTW, you can use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`. Please check this document: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: In this document, it says "Caution: While you can return any object, you should never pass an object that is tied to the Activity, such as a Drawable, an Adapter, a View or any other object that's associated with a Context. If you do, it will leak all the views and resources of the original activity instance. (Leaking resources means that your application maintains a hold on them and they cannot be garbage-collected, so lots of memory can be lost.)"  -- How will I use it for my adapter then?